# Storing a string from code memory to IDATA memory in C (8051)

Tags: c, 8051

I have the following code of line which stores the string TesT in the code memory of the 8051 micro-controller.

```
char code  *text_to_compare = "TesT";
```

How can I store the same string in the IDATA memory starting from 92Hex?

Answer (score 0):

After power up the idata memory contains more or less random values.
Some registers have known values but apart from that the only known data is the program code in rom, eprom or something similar.
If you want to have your data values in idata memory you have to tell the processor to write it to that place.
You can do that 'manually'. For example like that:

```
char code  *text_to_compare = "TesT";
char idata idataBuffer[5];

void copyToIdata(void) 
{
    unsigned char i;
    for (i = 0; (i < sizeof(idataBuffer)/sizeof(idataBuffer[0])); i++ )
    {
        /* Fetch data byte from code memory */
        char tmpChar = text_to_compare[i];

        /* Write data byte to idata memory */
        idataBuffer[i] = tmpChar;

        /* stop copying if end of string is reached */
        if (tmpChar == '\0')
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can ask the C compiler to generate the code for you. The copying will then be done in the boot code between reset and your main function:

```
char idata idataBuffer[5] = {'T', 'e', 's', 'T', '\0'};
```

If it is necessary that the idataBuffer starts at address 0x92 in RAM, you can tell the linker to place it there.

Please note: Actually I have no c51 compiler here. Therefore I could not check if the code really compiles and works. But I hope it gives you a rough Idea.

Best regards

Helmut